# Open link in a new tab from button clicked within iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

```
    <head>
</head>
<div> 
    <iframe src="https://....."></iframe>
</div>
```

[image: button within iFrame]

I was wondering how could I open up the link on a new tab on click of this button, as at the moment whenever the button is clicked, the page loads within the iFrame.. 
i have tried `<base target="_blank">` but does not really seems to work..

Comment: Don’t give us _“I have tried [vague explanation here] but does not really seems to work”_, but show us _exactly_ what you tried. Right now for example we have no idea _where_ you “tried” this - in the document that is loaded inside the iframe, or … elsewhere?

Comment: Also, please tag appropriately. Right now, nothing of what you have shown has anything whatsoever to do with `vue.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the iframe is same domain, set the button onclick to:

```
window.open(url , '_blank')
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To open a link in a new tab, as other users said you should use inside the iframe:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">link</a>
```

If you are in the same domain you could perform this without problem because of [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Inherited_origins) but if iframe is from a different domain you have to delegate that privilege with [sandbox property](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) , but unfortunately this have different behaviors in different browsers and in different versions of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Is the iframe from the same domain? If not, there can be problems.

For now, try this

```
<a target="_parent">click me</a>
```

or

```
<a target="_top">click me</a>
```

Besides, are you sure it's not a XY Problem  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: ^  This needs to be a comment

Comment: No, it is not from the same domain

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do, CORS restricts this

Comment: @HeyabRedda I'm afraid Hudson is right, if it's cross-domain you can't do much. But again, what are you really trying to achieve? Maybe we can help if we know the real problem :)

Answer (score 0):

use the following attribute in the Iframe tag

```
target="_blank"
```